# Move the phase in Controlled-Controlled-Phased-Gate

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state

I wonder how we can move the phase in CCZ gate onto different diagonal element
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & e^{i\phi}
\end{array}\right).
$$

Some people suggest me to use bit flip gate but I don't understand the bit flip gate effect and how it can do that. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

First, lets think about what this gate is doing, if the input is a computational basis state, $|b\rangle$ where $b$ is some 3 bit string, the action of the gate is nothing, unless $b = 111$, in which case it adds a global phase $e^{i\phi}$.

Suppose we had a more generalized version of this gate where the phase is on a different entry along the diagonal. This amounts to almost the same thing, except the particular state that it adds a global phase to is not $b = 111$ but a different bit string. For example, if the $e^{i\phi}$ factor was in the top left most position, it adds a phase only when $b = 000$.

You can *use* the CCZ gate to build such a gate, by mapping the state you want to the $111$ state. For example, if we want to move the $e^{i\phi}$ factor to the top left corner, we can apply a bit flip to each element, then the CCZ gate.

Comment: Ah, I got it. We can apply a bit flip gate to change the computational basis state and then apply CCZ gate. I came to this problem when trying to decompose 8x8 unitary matrix $U_j(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)$ into $e^{i l} P_1(i) \otimes P_2(j) \otimes P_3(k)$ and using CCZ to control the degree of freedom and cancel out the latter. If we can apply a bit flip gate, how can we represent it in terms of a mathematical formula? Sorry if my question is too naive. [link](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/28504/how-to-decompose-8x8-unitary-matrix-into-tensor-product-of-three-phased-gate)

Comment: I dont understand your question